# How to get object(or it's index in NumPy array) from mouse coordinates using collide rect or something else? (Pygame 2D)

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, 2d

Basically, I have a NumPy array of rectangles that store their colour and position.
I want to be able to compare my mouse position and clicked on the rectangle's position and get the index or the object itself from the array.

Do I have to iterate through every square in the array and compare item's coordinates?

The Structure looks like:

```py
Cube[Face][Horizontal-Line][Square] = np.array([colour, pygame.Rect(x, y, size, size)])
```

What's the most efficient to do it. I'm thinking of using colliderect() method, but I don't know how to implement it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQyxn.png

If you need more data, I will provide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to create a list  of rectangle:

```py
rect_list = [rect1, rect2, rect3 ...]
```

The mouse position (in the following `mouse_pos`) is a point, not rectangle. Use [`collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to find the intersection of a rectangle and a point:

```py
collide_rect_index = -1
for i, rect in enumerate(rect_list):
    if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        collide_rect_index = i
        break
```

Alternatively you can use [`collidelist()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist):

> Test whether the rectangle collides with any in a sequence of rectangles. The index of the first collision found is returned. If no collisions are found an index of -1 is returned.

Create a 1x1 rectangle at the mouse position and find the index of the colliding rectangle in the list of rectangles:

```py
mouse_rect = pygame.Rect(*mouse_pos, 1, 1)
collide_rect_index = mouse_rect.collidelest(rect_list)
```

---

However, if you have a grid, you can find the tile index (`row`, `column`) by dividing the mouse position (`mouse_pos`) by the size of a tile (`tile_size`). The row and column has to be integral. Hence you have to use the floor division (`//`) operator:

```py
column = mouse_pos[0] // tile_size
row    = mouse_pos[1] // tile_size
```